# C++ List Iterators accessing different elements in the same object

Tags: c++, class, list, object

for List Iterators i can access different elements

but i can only access one thing per object
 eg

```
class student{
private : 
string firstname;
string lastname;
// some other variables //etc...  

public: 
// some functions here ....
};
```

in the list i can access and print all the first name with the List Iterators
but how do I print 
first name follow by last name in a List ?

Comment: What is a List? an std::list?

Comment: And why can't you just do the same thing for the last name as you do for the first name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I think you're talking about: if not, please give some more details.

I take it you've got a `std::list` of `student`, like

```
std::list<student> studentList;
//add student instances to list
```

And then you're iterating over it, something like so:

```
for(std::list<student>::it = studentList.begin(); it != studentList.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << it->getFirstName() << std::endl;
}
```

If this is the case, just add a bit more for `it->getLastName()`:

```
for(std::list<student>::it = studentList.begin(); it != studentList.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << it->getFirstName() << " " << it->getSecondName() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print `lastname` in the same way, you print the `firstname`. If you print it in a member function of the class, then you can do this:

```
std::cout <<firstname <<" " <<lastname << std::endl;
```

And if you've written some `get` functions , and you print it from non-member function of the class, then you can do this:

```
student s;
//...
std::cout <<s.getFirstname() <<" " <<s.getLastname() << std::endl;
```

---

You can also add `operator<<` friend function to the class, as:

```
class student{
private : 
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    // some other variables //etc...  

public: 
    // some functions here ....
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & out, const student &s)
    {
       return out << s.firstname <<" " <<s.lastname;
    }
};
```

then do this:

```
std::list<student> students;
//...

for(std::list<student>::iterator it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++ )
{
      std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

And you can do even this:

```
student s;
//...
std::cout << s << std::endl; //it prints firstname and lastname by calling operator<<
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple !  **cout** the firstname it followed by the last name.

```
cout << lIter->firstName << " " << lIter->lastName << endl ;
// firstName, lastName are private. So, intead write getters and call those on list iterator.
```

Or did I understand the question wrong ?

Comment: hum i did that and it only keep the last  thing in the cout before the endl which  is the last name in your case for some reason